# Function that takes the limit as an argument of the Fibonacci series and prints till that limit in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've to write a function that takes the limit as an argument of the Fibonacci series and prints till that limit. Here, if the limit is `fibonacci(10)` then the output should be `0 1 1 2 3 5 8`

I tried:

```
def fibonacci(number):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    print(a,end = ' ')
    print(b, end = ' ')
    
    for num in range( 2 , number):
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        print(c, end = " ")
        

fibonacci(10)
```

The output came:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just add a check to see if the number resulting from `a+b` is going to be larger than the limit.

```
for num in range( 2 , number):
        if a+b > number: return
        
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        print(c, end = " ")
```

Output:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8
```

The break statement exits the for loop so that no numbers over the limit will be printed. You can also use `return` instead of `break`. However, if you end up adding logic **after the for loop**, it will not be reached because `return` will exit the entire function.

****SUGGESTION**** (courtesy of @OneCricketeer)

You may also use a `while` loop here instead of a range. This achieves the same output with cleaner, easier to understand code.

```
while (a+b < number):
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        print(c, end = " ")
```

Comment: Should really use a while loop than a range

Comment: @OneCricketeer Great suggestion. Didn't want to throw a completely different solution at the OP, but will include this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fibonacci(limit):
    a=0
    b=1
    print(a,end=" ") 
    print(b,end=" ")
    for i in range(limit):
        c=a+b
        if c<=limit:
            print(c,end=" ")
        a=b
        b=c
x=int(input())
fibonacci(x)
```

**Input:**
`10`

**Output:**
`0 1 1 2 3 5 8`